# Como acessar um elemento (ou seus valores) gerado dinamicamente?

Tags: jquery

Sei que é possível usar o `on()` e delegar o seletor, assim ele acessa o elemento dinâmico a partir de um elemento estático, mas se não tiver como usar o `on()`, o que fazer?

Por exemplo, dentro de uma função qualquer eu preciso pegar o id de um elemento adicionado dinamicamente para mudar um atributo de estilo e não existe um evento que dispare o `on()`:

**jQuery**

```
function(){
    if(1 + 1 == 2){
        //Não vejo como usar o on() nessa situação.
        $("#elemento").css("color", "black");
    }
    //Talvez...
    $("#elemento2").on((1 + 1 == 2), "#elemento", function(){
        $("#elemento").css("color", "black");
    });
}
```

Existe algum outro método, como gerar ações que independam de outras ações do usuário ou é impossível fazer isso com jQuery?

Comment: Não entendi! O que deseja fazer? Você poderia explicar resumidamente.

Comment: Você quer então uma maneira de seu script sempre ficar de olho e poder interagir com novos elementos inseridos no DOM, sem ficar preso a eventos do cursor como o hover e o click?
Acredito que uma boa são os **Mutations Observers**, mas eu ainda não tenho uma prática muito bacana com eles.

Comment: @MarcosFreitas, exato, quero gerar ações que independam do usuário, vou adicionar essa afirmação na pergunta, talvez a deixe mais esclarecida.

Comment: Pois bem, assim só posso te ajudar indicando esse artigo sobre os **M. Observers**: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers

Comment: Você quer algo como um evento que dispare quando um estilo é alterado? Ou você quer somente selecionar o elemento com jQuery?

Comment: No caso, selecionar o elemento com jQuery, no exemplo o `#elemento` deveria mudar a cor da fonte quando 1 + 1 for igual a 2, mas isso não acontece, pois o `#elemento` é adicionado dinamicamente.

Comment: @Patrick tem algum caso concreto que lhe levantou essa questão? se __sim__ por favor coloque o código todo ou crie uma situação específica onde este problema surge. Para ser honesto ainda não percebí o que procura fazer...

Comment: Já agora dê uma olhada aqui, no caso de ser isto que procura: https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery

Comment: Adicionei mais um exemplo ao código, não sei se vai ajudar a entender...

Comment: Se a ação que você quer que seja disparada seja sempre a mesma, porque você não usa classes CSS quando for criar os elementos dinâmicos?

Comment: @Kazzkiq, algo como `display: none` e depois `display: block`?

Comment: Patrick, qual é o problema com o código que você postou (primeiro if)? Ele funciona contanto que o elemento exista na página. E se ele não existir, não faz sentido mudar a cor... Desculpe, mas continua difícil de entender o que você está procurando.

Comment: Imagine que o elemento fora adicionado dinamicamente, sem delegação ele não vai funcionar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que você está confuso sobre a necessidade de delegação. Quando você seleciona um elemento com jQuery – por exemplo, com `$('#algumId')` –, o elemento só é selecionado se ele existir. Se ele não existir, você não pode fazer nada com ele (como alterar conteúdo, atributos, ou associar uma função que trate um evento nesse elemento).

*Delegação de eventos* é uma forma de se definir como tratar eventos em determinado elemento antes mesmo de ele existir no DOM. Porém, na hora em que o evento é disparado, o elemento naturalmente precisa já existir no DOM para que sua função delegada faça alguma coisa.

Se você quer alterar o conteúdo ou atributo do elemento, basta fazer isso diretamente:

```
function pintaDePreto(){
    $("#elemento").css("color", "black");
}
```

Não faz sentido falar em delegação nesse caso, não há eventos envolvidos. Se o elemento `#elemento` existir quando a função for chamada, será aplicado `color: black` nele. Se ele não existir, nada acontece. Isso não tem a ver com o elemento ser ou não adicionado dinamicamente, e sim com a própria existência do elemento no DOM. Se ele não existir, não faz sentido querer mudar a cor! Então apenas garanta que a função será chamada quando o elemento alvo existir.

Comment: Então se usa delegação apenas onde existem eventos, caso contrário, basta fazer como no seu exemplo?

Comment: Isso, na verdade o que se chama "delegação" é *event delegation*, portanto delegação **de eventos**.